# Convergence of operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I have a linear bounded operator $A:L_2(0,1) \rightarrow L_2(0,1)$ satisfying $\|A^n\|^{1/n} \rightarrow 0$. Thus, for some sufficiently large $N$, $\|A^N\| < 1$ and then from Gelfand's formula, I can show that the spectral radius of $A$ satisfies $\rho(A)<1$.

My question is, knowing these properties of the operator $A$, what can we say about the spectral radius of the operator $A+A^\star$, where $A^\star$ is the adjoint of $A$?

Since I can find the spectral radius as the limit of a sequence of operator norms, I want to construct $\|(A+A^\star)^n\|$ and I know that $\|A^n\|=\|(A^\star)^n\|$, but I don't know how to relate $\|(A+A^\star)^n\|$ and   $\|A^n\|$.

If any one's interested, the operator $A$ is the volterra operator given by $(Aw)(x)=\int_0^x K(x,\xi)w(\xi)d \xi$ for a continuous $K$. One can show that $\rho(A)=0$ and $\rho(A^\star)=0$, but I have no idea about $\rho(A+A^\star)$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Gelfand's formula, [which holds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra#Spectral_theory) for every element of a unital complex Banach algebra more generally,
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\|A^n\|^\frac{1}{n}=0\quad\iff\quad \rho(A)=0.
$$
This characterizes the set of quasinilpotent operators, which extends the set of nilpotent operators.

There is nothing you can say about $\rho(A+A^*)$ without further assumptions. Indeed, for every $t\geq 0$,
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&t\\0&0}\quad\Rightarrow\quad A+A^*=\pmatrix{0&t\\t&0}\quad\Rightarrow\quad \sigma(A+A^*)=\{\pm t\}\quad\Rightarrow\quad \rho(A+A^*)=t.
$$
So $\rho(A+A^*)$ could be any nonnegative number and yet $\rho(A)=0$.

**Note:** the question is more interesting if you add the condition that the self-adjoint operator $A+A^*$ be positive (i.e. has nonnegative spectrum). In finite dimension, we have
$$
\rho(A)=0\quad\mbox{and}\quad A+A^*\geq 0\quad \Rightarrow\quad A=0.
$$
Indeed, the condition $\rho(A)=0$ implies $\mbox{Tr} A=0$, whence $\mbox{Tr}(A+A^*)=0$. Now if $A+A^*\geq 0$ has null trace, it follows that every eigenvalue is zero. Since $A+A^*$ is diagonalizable, this entails $A+A^*=0$. So $A=-A^*$ is normal, whence diagonalizable with null spectrum. Therefore $A=0$.

This argument seems to extend without difficulty to the trace-class quasinilpotent operators when $H$ is infinite-dimensional separable. I don't know at this point what happens in full generality. Help anybody?

**Edit:** I was given the answer on MO by Mike Jury. In infinite dimension, you can have $A$ quasinilpotent, nonzero, and yet $A+A^*\geq 0$. It suffices to consider the Volterra operator...

Comment: Hi Julien, thanks for providing a example and yes, I am aware that these operators are quasinilpotent. There is an additional property that the operator $A+A^\star$ is a non-negative operator. However, I don't think that has any bearing on my problem.

Comment: I was wondering, are there any results on the spectra of the product of quasinilpotent operators?

Comment: @Amit  If they commute, the product is still quasinilpotent. If they don't, the spectral radius of the product could be anything.

Comment: Ok, I think I have sufficient information now to at least attempt a stab at obtaining my desired results. Thanks a lot Julien.

Comment: @Amit You're welcome. I've added some thoughts about the case when you assume $A+A^*\geq 0$. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I'm the "wrong" Martin, but I think I can help (according to the comments to [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9084/) Martin A. won't get a notification). For a self-adjoint operator $T$ we have $\rho(T) = \lVert T\rVert$, in particular $\rho(T) = 0$ implies $T = 0$ (without assuming positivity). Indeed,  $T^2 = T^\ast T$ so that $\lVert T^2 \rVert = \lVert T \rVert^2$ by the C\*-identity. By induction $\lVert T^{2^n}\rVert = \lVert T\rVert^{2^n}$ and using Gelfand's formula, we get $\rho(T) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \lVert T^{2^n}\rVert^{2^{-n}} = \lVert T \rVert$.

Comment: @Martin I was thinking about you too, actually, but I didn't want to start calling on every FA expert! Now regarding your comment, the problem is that $\rho(A)=0$ does not imply $\rho(A+A^*)=0$. At least not directly. Just lookt at my trivial counterexamples above.

Comment: Oh, I misread your comment (I parsed it as $\rho(A + A^\ast) = 0$), sorry. (And thanks for calling me an expert :-))

Comment: Thank you for all your constructive comments. Julien, thanks a lot. With the operator $A$ defined using the polynomial integral $K(x,\xi)$ as I have defined in my original post, if $\sup_{x,\xi}K(x,\xi)<1$, then it can be shown that $A+A^*$ is a contraction. From this, one can deduce that the spectral radius of $A+A^*$ is zero.

Comment: @Martin The Volterra operator...

Comment: Oh my... There it was, right in front of our eyes! :-)

Comment: @Martin I know. And that was only my second contribution to MO...I'd better not do that again, I think. This being said, I find these facts interesting. If $A\neq 0$ is quasinilpotent, $A+A^*$ must have some positive and some negative spectrum in finite dimension. Not true in infinite dimension. I still don't know if $A+A^*$ can be positive invertible...